# Blazor Server: Accesing Data From Code Behind To The Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to access some data from the DB so I can display it on the home page as "featured" or "hot" vehicles. In my code behind, I keep getting "Bus is a namespace but used as a type" error. I cant find where Bus is a namespace.

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"

@foreach (var bus in buses)
{
    <h1>@bus.Make</h1>
}
```

**Index.razor.cs**

```
namespace CarLot.Pages
{
    public partial class Index : ComponentBase
    {

        [Inject]
        public BusService busService { get; set; }
        public List<Bus> buses { get; set; }
       

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {

            buses = await busService.GetFeaturedBuses();
        }


    }
}
```

Instead of `public List<Bus> buses { get; set; }` I have tried `public List<Models.Bus> buses { get; set; }` in the **Index.razor.cs** file. The namespace error goes away but, when I start the app, I get the error CarLot.Pages.Index.buses.get returned null in the **Index.razor** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a namespace issue previously. If you have previously created a folder called `Bus` in the project and renamed it to something else, in that case sometimes visual studio caches it. Try to clean your project and if the problem still exists, try deleting .vs hidden folder and the bin+obj folders just in case.

Regarding null reference exception, you will have to either initialize `buses` property or wrap your use of `buses` inside a null check. See code below:

Option 1 `Index.razor`:

```
@page "/"

@if(buses != null)
{
    @foreach (var bus in buses)
    {
        <h1>@bus.Make</h1>
    }
}
```

Option 2 `Index.razor.cs`:

```
public List<Bus> buses { get; set; } = new List<Bus>();
```

Comment: Just looked, I do have a folder under Pages named Bus...I will delete that folder and initialize the buses property. Thank you for your quick response.